# Convert date to string in java?

Tags: java, date, date-format, simpledateformat

In my code  I am getting date as this String:

```
date="2013-06-15"
```

I want it to convert to 15 Jun 2013 . I have tried dateFormat:

```
DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-mm-dd");
String date = df.format(det);   
DateFormat f2 = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-mmmm-yyyy");
date=f2.format(date).toLowerCase();
out.println("DATE"+date);
```

But it gave null pointer Could Anyone help me doing this.Please help?

Comment: "String date = df.format(det);" what is det?

Comment: Where is the NPE thrown?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

first convert your Date string to Date then convert it to your required format

```
package naveed.workingfiles;

import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.Locale;

public class DateToString {

public static void main(String[] args) {

String laDate="2013-06-15";
String dateString = laDate.substring(8, 10) + "/"
            + laDate.substring(5, 7) + "/"
            + laDate.substring(0, 4);
Date date= new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy").parse(dateString);
String dateFormat = "dd-MMM-yyyy";
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat(dateFormat, new Locale("en_US"));
String tDate = sdf.format(date);
System.out.println(tDate);//here your String date 

}

}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
String dateString="2013-06-15";
Date date = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd").parse(dateString);
DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MMM-yyyy");
DateFormat df2 = new SimpleDateFormat("dd MMM yyyy");
System.out.println(df.format(date).toLowerCase());//print 15-jun-2013
System.out.println(df.format(date));//print 15-Jun-2013
System.out.println(df2.format(date));//print 15 Jun 2013
```

Answer (score 1):

```
// Create an instance of SimpleDateFormat used for formatting 
// the string representation of date (month/day/year)
DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss");

// Get the date today using Calendar object.
Date today = Calendar.getInstance().getTime();        
// Using DateFormat format method we can create a string 
// representation of a date with the defined format.
String reportDate = df.format(today);

// Print what date is today!
System.out.println("Report Date: " + reportDate);
```

Answer (score 1):

This is not gonna work: [`format()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/text/DateFormat.html#format%28java.util.Date%29) does not take String parameters:

```
String date = df.format(det);   
DateFormat f2 = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-mmmm-yyyy");
date=f2.format(date).toLowerCase();
```

Try this:

```
String dateAsString = "2013-06-15"
DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
Date date = df.parse(dateAsString);   
df = new SimpleDateFormat("dd MMM yyyy");
out.println("DATE"+df.format(date));
```

Comment: This is actually wrong, M=Month, m =minute

Comment: @fareed thx. damn copy paste mistake ;)

Answer (score 1):

This will work

```
    String dateStr = "2013-06-15";
    DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
    Date date=df.parse(dateStr);
    DateFormat f2 = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MMM-yyyy");
    System.out.println(f2.format(date));
```